# Can't calculate the total cost in my restaurant menu program

Tags: python

So I am making a restaurant menu in Python, I got everything to work besides the program keeping track of the total cost. I've tried a few different things but no luck so far. It's probably something super simple but I can't figure it out. P.S. I'm a Python beginner so I'm still trying to get used to and learn this language lmao.

```
print("1. Cheeseburger: $3.50")
print("2. Gyro: $6.00")
print("3. Chicken Sandwich: $2.50")
print("4. Burrito: $7.00")
print("5. Fries: $1.50")
print("6. Exit")

while True:
    choice = input("Enter a choice from 1-6\n")
    totalPrice = 0
    if choice == "1":
        price = 3.00
        totalPrice += price
    elif choice == "2":
        price = 6.00
        totalPrice += price
    elif choice == "3":
        price = 2.50
        totalPrice += price
    elif choice == "4":
        price = 7.00
        totalPrice += price
    elif choice == "5":
        price = 1.50
        totalPrice += price
    elif choice == "6":
        print("Exiting...")
        print(totalPrice)
        break
    else:
        print("Enter a valid choice!")
```

Comment: You reset "totalPrice" to 0 each time after user made a choice. Place the assignment to 0 before the while-loop instead.

Comment: you print $3.50 for the cheeseburger but only add 3 to the price

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Only a litle mistake: the variable `totalPrice` must be initialized outside of the loop.

See the code below:

```
print("1. Cheeseburger: $3.50")
print("2. Gyro: $6.00")
print("3. Chicken Sandwich: $2.50")
print("4. Burrito: $7.00")
print("5. Fries: $1.50")
print("6. Exit")

totalPrice = 0  # <--- here is the right position for init totalPrice
while True:
    choice = input("Enter a choice from 1-6\n")
    if choice == "1":
        price = 3.00
        totalPrice += price
    elif choice == "2":
        price = 6.00
        totalPrice += price
    elif choice == "3":
        price = 2.50
        totalPrice += price
    elif choice == "4":
        price = 7.00
        totalPrice += price
    elif choice == "5":
        price = 1.50
        totalPrice += price
    elif choice == "6":
        print("Exiting...")
        print(totalPrice)
        break
    else:
        print("Enter a valid choice!")
```